# crontab not working as expected

Tags: cron, scheduled

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and  I want to execute a script every 5 hours .
I setup cron with crontab -e and putted

```
* */5 * * * sh /home/cron_script.sh
```

The script is executed every minute.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first * needs to be a 0 or whatever minute of the hour you want the script to run...eg 30 would mean script will run at 0030,0530, 1030, etc.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is this:

```
0 */5 * * * sh /home/cron_script.sh
```